# GTLObject.h file not found GTLCalendar and GoogleOpernSource framework

Tags: ios, file-not-found

Works fine in release mode but not in debug. Settings seem to be identical, but if they are not I cannot see what is different. Apparently GTL_BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK is not defined in debug mode. Everything is included by reference into project.

in GTLCalendarEventAttendee.h

```
#if GTL_BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK 
  #import "GTL/GTLObject.h"
#else
  #import "GTLObject.h"
#endif
```

Comment: Nope .. have tried a number of things nothing helps. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I make it work (I don't know how), but I got an other error with google-api ...